# How can I update labels which are located different windows synchronically in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

How can update labels located different windows and different python scripts  in tkinter. I used TopLevel() and global for this change but I cannot delete previous text which is written on the label. When I used config() I see this error:

STEPI_LABEL =tk.config(text=f"Bad Character {total}", font=("Arial", 24, "bold"))
AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'config'

page 1:

```
STEPI_LABEL.grid(column=19,row=4)
STEPII_LABEL=Label(text="I am a label",font=("Arial",24,"bold"))
STEPII_LABEL.config(text="STEPII_LABEL")
```

page2: (OOP class)

```
global STEPI_LABEL

            STEPI_LABEL =tk.config(text=f"Bad Character {total}", font=("Arial", 24, "bold"))
            STEPI_LABEL.grid(column=19, row=4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `tk` itself has no attribute `config` is because it is not a widget; it is a module. Only widgets (like `Tk`, `Label`, `TopLevel`, etc.) have a `config()` function. The `config()` function is used to change widgets that already exist; it cannot be used to create widgets. In your code, you try to create `STEPI_LABEL` by using `config()`; use `Label()` instead:

```py
global STEPI_LABEL

STEPI_LABEL = tk.Label(text=f"Bad Character {total}", font=("Arial", 24, "bold"))
STEPI_LABEL.grid(column=19, row=4)
```

If you want to change the label later (for instance, change it's text) *then* you can use `config()`:

```py
STEPI_LABEL.config(text=f"Not a bad character {total}")
```

Any arguments that can be passed to `Label()` on creation, except for `master`, can be used in `config()` as well.